# Adding a unique name to cloned form elements

Tags: javascript, appendchild, clonenode

We are using the following code to create a form that can be extended with the press of a button, but we are having trouble adding a unique name to the input fields. We had it working to add a unique ID, but when we changed it to the name it stopped working. Help? :( Many thanks for any advice.

```
var counter = 0
function cloneRow() {
   counter ++;      
   var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
   var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
   var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
   var theName= row.name;
   clone.name = theName + counter++; // change id or other attributes/contents
   table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too

    var theName= row.getAttribute('name');

    clone.setAttribute('name', theName + counter++);// change id or other attributes/contents
```

Answer (score 1):

You're no-longer setting an *id* attribute, and you're now double-incrementing `counter` and the [*name* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.name) doesn't apply to this type of [*Element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), so you'll have to specifically [get the *attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute). See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DXuE2/).

> name gets or sets the name attribute of an DOM object, it only applies to the following elements: `<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>,` and `<textarea>.`

```
var counter = 0;

function cloneRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"),      // row to copy
        table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"), // table to append to
        clone = row.cloneNode(true),                      // clone with children
        theName = row.getAttribute('name') + ++counter;   // get name attribute
        // inc counter there, too

    clone.setAttribute('name', theName); // re-set name
    clone.setAttribute('id', theName);   // set ID (lost during clone)
    table.appendChild(clone);            // add new row to end of table
}
```

Comment: +1, but better to get the OP to go back to using a standard attribute than a non–standard one.